# Flutter Showing Snackbar On Top of Bottom Sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-snackbar, flutter-widget

In my code I call a bottom sheet to display a list of tiles. These tiles contain buttons that display a snackbar. That functionality works fine, the only issue is that the snackbar is displayed behind the bottom sheet so you can only see it if you close the bottom sheet. Each of them are called with the following code:

**1. Bottom Sheet:**

```
  void _settingModalBottomSheet(context, stream, scaffoldKey ) {
    if (_availableRides.length == 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((context) {
        return Column(
          children: Widgets;
      });
    }
  }
```

**2. Snackbar**

```
widget.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
         content: Text("Created", textAlign: 
    TextAlign.center,),),
```

Does anyone know how I can position the snackbar in front of the bottom sheet

Answer (score 22):

So I was able to solve this by just adding another Scaffold() to my Bottom sheet and passing it a new scaffold key

Comment: Oh, my god. I just refactored to use a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` everywhere to show a `SnackBar` because `BottomSheet` doesn't have access to its parent `Scaffold`, and now I have to trash everything.

Comment: can you share some snippet

Comment: showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => **Scaffold(
   // your body here
)**);

Comment: This is not a good solution as the bottom sheet now takes the entire screen height!

Comment: @SwiftiSwift You can wrap the `Scaffold()` with `SizedBox` to limit the bottom sheet height.

Comment: @dipansh I don't want to define a fixed height rather it should be dynamically based on its body

Answer (score 6):

`SnackBar` has a `property` for this. It's called `behavior`, you could do this:

```
SnackBar(
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    ...
```

[SnackBarBehavior enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBarBehavior.html)

> floating → const SnackBarBehavior
>
> This behavior will cause SnackBar to be shown above other widgets in
> the Scaffold. This includes being displayed above a
> BottomNavigationBar and a FloatingActionButton.
>
> See material.io/design/components/snackbars.html for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it shows higher than a bottom sheet and even a FAB, which looks weird. I wish there was an option to show it at the bottom, as in SnackBarBehavior.fixed, but over the bottom sheet.

Comment: Sorry to say, but suggested solution did not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh I a now I am late to the party, but take a look to my answer It worked for me.

Comment: The answer doesnt goes with what is asked.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem with idle solution but it works

The Solution by 3 steps:

1 Add `SizedBox` and set the same height of BottomSheet
2 Add `Scaffold` as child of SizedBox
3 Add Your BottomSheet

```
SizedBox(
  height: ... ,// height of bottomSheet
  child: Scaffold(
       body: ... , // your bottomSheet
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I arrived on pretty decent solution. I wrapped my bottom sheet in a `Scaffold`, but I added it as the `bottomSheet` parameter. While adding the `Scaffold`, some trailing background will be added, so I just made its  background transparent.

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  bottomSheet: ...,
)
```

Comment: the `bottomSheet` has to be body for the `backgroundColor` to take effect.

Comment: For me the, the transparency did not work. However, we can wrap the Scaffold with a SizedBox that only has a specific height (considering we always want that for the bottomSheetLayout), example:

SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomSheet: <your content>
       ),
  )

Answer (score 2):

I solved by Set (padding from bottom to SnackBar) As much as the height of the (bottomSheet : height) .

In This Case I Have This bottomSheet:

```
bottomSheet: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(...),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: AppBar().preferredSize.height * 0.85,
        ),
```

And This snackBar:

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
padding:EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
bottom:AppBar().preferredSize.height * 0.85),
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
content: Text('ETC..'),
                ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this Simply by wrapping your BottomSheet widget with a Scaffold.

eg:

```dart
 void _settingModalBottomSheet(context, stream, scaffoldKey ) {
    if (_availableRides.length == 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((context) {
        return Scaffold(
           body: Column(
             children: Widgets;
           })
         );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working solution according to documentation.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars

This example works with bottom sheets as well.

1. Initialize `ScaffoldMessengerKey`.
2. Wrap your component widget with `Scaffold`.
3. Wrap `Scaffold` with `ScaffoldMessenger`.
4. Add key `scaffoldMessengerKey` to `ScaffoldMessenger`
5. Call method `scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar());`

Example:

```
final scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();


// Any widget with button. 
// (Bottom sheet also) - root widget must be ScaffoldMessenger.
ScaffoldMessenger(
  key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: raisedButtonStyle,
        onPressed: () { 
          scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
            //SnackBar design.
            SnackBar(
             backgroundColor: Colors.white,
             elevation: 8,
             content: Container(
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
               ),
               child: Text(
                 'Simple snackbar text.',
                 style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1
                 .override(fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          lineHeight: 1.5,
               ),
             ),
             action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Undo',
                onPressed: () {
                  // Some code to undo the change.
                },
             ),
             duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
             behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
               
       },
       child: Text('Open snackbar over bottom sheet!'),
      ); //ElevatedButton
    ); //Container
  ); //Scaffold
); //ScaffoldMessenger
```

Note:
With this approach you don't need to pass BuildContext.

If you don't want to register `ScaffoldMessengerKey`.
You can show SnackBar like this:  `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar());`

Comment: This is not a good solution as the bottom sheet now takes the entire screen height!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing `bottomSheet` to `bottomNavigationBar` since the floating snack bar solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Where did you make this change? kindly share. Thanks.

Comment: `Scaffold` has both bottomSheet and bottomNavigationBar properties. When the scaffold had a bottomSheet widget, the snackbar would not display in front of the widget. When I changed it to bottomNavigation bar, the snackbar displayed in front of the widget.

Comment: I already have a bottomNavigationBar, bottomModelSheet and snackbar. bottomModelSheet is displaying as overlay of bottomNavigationBar which is working. But when I want to show snackbar over the bottomModelSheet it does not displayed. Snackbar is displayed between bottomNavigationBar and bottomModelSheet. If you have any experience of it. Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i am facing same issue as Kamlesh

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar) package. I think this is the better option if need to use with bottomSheet.

context should be your page's context, not bottomsheet context

any event inside bottomSheet

```
 CustomFlushBar().flushBar(text: 'Thank you for your payment!', context: context,duration: 2);
```

**CustomFlushBar class**

```
  class CustomFlushBar {
      void flushBar({int duration, @required String text, Color iconColor, IconData iconData, Color backgroundColor, @required BuildContext context}) async {
        await dismiss();
        Flushbar(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          borderRadius: 8,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? Palette.greenButton,
          icon: Icon(iconData ?? Icons.done, color: iconColor ?? Palette.white),
          flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
          message: text,
          duration: Duration(seconds: duration ?? 3),
        )..show(context);
      }
    
      Future<void> dismiss() async {
        if (!Flushbar().isDismissed()) {
          await Flushbar().dismiss();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @AnandKumar `context` should be your page's context, not bottomsheet context